# Getting a Random hexadecimal using an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, colors, hex

I have written a little code that generates a random color. It is based in an array that goes from 0 to 9 and A,B,C,D,E,F:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejercicio 7</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeColor() {
            const intensity = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
            let randomColor1 = intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)];
            let randomColor2 = intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)];
            let randomColor3 = intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)];
            let randomColor4 = intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)];
            let randomColor5 = intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)];
            let randomColor6 = intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)];
            const randomColor = `#${randomColor1}${randomColor2}${randomColor3}${randomColor4}${randomColor5}${randomColor6}`;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="changeColor()">
    <button onclick="changeColor()">Pincha aquí</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is I don't understand this piece of repeated code:

```
intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)]
```

I know it gives me a random element from the array "intensity", but I don't know  how it works. Can someone explain to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Basics of generating a random number in a range. `var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length); var color = intensity[x]

Comment: That's overly complex, see [`Number.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: thanks, I saw that question, but I din't really understood the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Math.random()` you get a number (float) between 0 and 1 (but not 1 as Andreas points out).

If you want a number from 0 to X you have to multiply for X `Math.random() * X`.

And the index of intensity goes from `0` to `intensity.length`.

That's why you need `Math.random() * intensity.length` to get an index of intensity randomly.

As the result of this multiplication is a float you can use floor to strip decimals and then you have at this moment:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)`

Which is the random index of intensity to get:

```
intensity[Math.floor(Math.random() * intensity.length)]
```

Comment: _"The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (**nclusive of 0, but not 1**)"_

Comment: The cero is after the nine, I forgot to write it for starting so I wrote it after the 9. Ok, now I understand it much better. I've done tests and now I get everything in the syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may find a lot of examples of random hex color generators online, for example, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/:

```
function randomHexColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I can find many examples. The thing on the color was just  the excuse to get a proper explanation on how Math.floor and Math.random work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Basically `Math.random()` generates a random number between 0 and 1, something like 0.12345. To get a random number between 0 and n, you generate a random number with `Math.random()` and multiply by N. 
The result will be something like 123.45, so you use `Math.foor` to convert it back to integer

Comment: thanks again. Now I am trying to understand the function randomHexColor... I'm googling it :)

Comment: got it! the hexadecimal and the value of 16777215 is related to colors and hexadecimal system... I didn't now that.

Comment: Yes, 16777215 in decimal, is converted to FFFFFF in hex, which happens to be the maximum value for the hex color